# Where's the EL&U blog gone?

Tags: bug, status-completed, blog

I tried to visit the [EL&U blog](http://english.blogoverflow.com) and I get redirected to the Stack Exchange blogs main page.

If I try to visit one of the EL&U posts that are listed on that page then I get 404'd

[image: 404 page where a blog page should be]

Where has the blog gone?

Comment: It's not just us: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221876/diy-blogoverflow-com-is-redirecting-to-stackexchange-com-blogs

Comment: This bug has been fixed. So, [tag: status-completed]?

Comment: So how come, in order for me to make a comment, it wants me to log in to Stack Exchange, where I always fail to log in successfully, after I got there from the link above, while logged in on ELU.meta? Nuts. It would be nice, but it's not to be, apparently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It wasn't just ELU, but has now been [fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222142/162511):

> This was an issue with the SOA and A records being cached really hard on some DNS servers for a day. We never had a TTL higher than 5 minutes on the A and no higher than an hour on the SOA at any point, so we're at a loss to explain why some downstream DNS servers chose to cache for a full day.
>
> The records in question are fixed now, but if you had this issue then beware your DNS server. It, or an upstream server, is not configured properly.